# Why does this command not run correctly in a scheduled task?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that creates a scheduled task to connect to Exchange Online. When I use a single ' the command runs fine, when I use a double " the command doesn't run (scheduled task stays in "Running" state:

The $Command is sent to the scheduled task.

```
`If  (($WPFDelegate_Flag.IsChecked -eq $False) -and ($WPFCan_View_Private_Items.IsChecked -eq $False) -and ($WPFSchedule_Start.IsChecked -eq $True) -and ($WPFSchedule_End.IsChecked -eq $False))
{
$Command =
@"
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$UserName = 'user@site.com'
$PasswordText = Get-Content C:\Users\User\Password\Secure.txt
$SecurePwd = $PasswordText | ConvertTo-SecureString
$CredObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePwd
connect-exchangeonline -Credential $credObject 
Remove-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $To_From_Email -User $Add_Remove_Email -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Ignore
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $To_From_Email -User $Add_Remove_Email -AccessRights "$Select_Permission"
"$TriggerDate,$WhoAmI,$TaskName,Grant Permissions,$Add_Remove_Email_Ref,$To_From_Email_Ref,$TriggerDate,$EndTriggerDate,$Select_Permission,No, No"|Add-Content -Path C:\Users\User\Logs\Calendar-Scheduled-Tasks-Log.csv
"@
$CommandBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes( $Command )
$CommandBase64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String( $CommandBytes )
$StartAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -EncodedCommand $CommandBase64" -ErrorAction Stop
$EndAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell.exe" -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden Unregister-ScheduledTask -Taskname $TaskName -Confirm:$false;Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName-Remove -Confirm:$false"
Get-MailboxFolderPermission $Add_Remove_Email -ErrorAction Stop
Get-MailboxFolderPermission $To_From_Email -ErrorAction Stop
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$TaskName" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Password $Password -Action $StartAction -ErrorAction Stop
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "$TaskName-Remove" -Trigger $EndTrigger -User $User -Password $Password -Action $EndAction
"$Today,$WhoAmI,$TaskName,Grant Permissions,$Add_Remove_Email_Ref,$To_From_Email_Ref,$TriggerDate,$EndTriggerDate,$Select_Permission,No, No"|Add-Content -Path C:\Users\User\Logs\Calendar-Permissions-Log.csv
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Task $TaskName is scheduled to run on $TriggerDate to apply permissions for user $Add_Remove_Email_Ref on user $To_From_Email_Ref calendar. Permissions to be applied: $Select_Permission."
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show(("Task $TaskName is scheduled to run on $TriggerDate to apply permissions for user $Add_Remove_Email_Ref on user $To_From_Email_Ref calendar. Permissions to be applied: $Select_Permission.")) 
}`
```

Comment: The reason I need to use the double " is because I need to call a variable that is outside of the script block. Essentially I would like the username and password to be pulled from another variable that is created earlier on in the script.

Comment: are the ```'``` you are talking about are the one before the ```if``` on the first line and after the ```}```on the last line?